# Function array - Modulo - Add 1 to every second element

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JS.
I need to add 1 to every second element (not every even);

I did:

```
const modifyEverySecondElement = (arr) =>  arr.map((n) => (n % 2)? n + 0 : n + 1);
```

But it add 1 to every even.

Comment: Also please convert this to normal function not arrow. 
I want to understand it better.

Comment: The best way to learn something is to work with it. Convert the arrow function to a normal function to understand it better.

Comment: every second element will be at an even index. Please be clear what exactly do you want?

Comment: Are you talking about `even` number or `even` position/index?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes the index as the second parameter. Note that from your text it is unclear, whether you want a new array, or "add 1 to every second element", mutating the original array.

Comment: @HR01M8055 "every second element (not every even)"

Comment: @jabaa I might have missed something while reading

Comment: @jabaa 
function modifyEverySeconElement_1(arr) {
arr.map = arr.map(n, index);
return ((index % 2) ? n + 1 : n);
}

This looks corect

Answer (score 2):

as I understand it:

```
const modifyEverySecondElement = arr.map((n, index) => (index % 2) ? n + 1 : n);
```

Comment: const modifyEverySecondElement = (arr) => arr.map((n, index) => (index % 2) ? n + 1 : n);